# CSS overflow-x isn't hiding when a div is positioned with a negative margin

Tags: css, html, scroll, margin

I have a div that is positioned with a negative margin so that it will be hidden and I will be able to fly it into the screen. However, I am able to scroll to the right and see it. I tried to change the `overflow-x` property in my body and html tags to hidden, and that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

My div is positioned with `margin-right:-800px` and nothing seems to work!

---

**EDITED CODE**

CSS code:

Hidden `div`:

```
.card{
    z-index:21;
    position:absolute;
    right:-800px;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding:20px;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(110,110,110,.7);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-100deg);
    -webkit-transition:right .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}
```

My overflow attempt:

```
html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:visible;
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code
?

Comment: please post you'r code rather than describing about it.

Comment: Code posted, look at the edit.

Comment: @arielschon12 : That's great, but what are you using to animate ? JavaScript/CSS ? And is there an action button after which the animation should start?

Comment: I don't have the rest of your HTML but this simple example (http://jsfiddle.net/Ktt4Z/) seems to render as desired.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as i did?

Comment: @arielschon12, it is and that's my point. It seems to work like you want. It's unclear what the problem is based on your question. Do you want it to fly in?

Comment: I have it flying in. I just dont want to be able to scroll to the right. I can't see the DIV cause its hidden, but there is a big white spot that i can scroll to. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pranav stated, we really don't know how you are creating the animation. However, here's a working example of some animation similar to what you are describing: http://jsfiddle.net/Ktt4Z/2/.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#box').animate({  textIndent: 0 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
    This is a test. This is a test.
</div>​
```

Also, here's a great resource on CSS `overflow`:
http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Finally, when posting a question it's best to post your code, an simple example using JSFiddle if possible, and anything you've tried. This will help the community in researching and discovering an answer to your question.

---

**EDIT 0**

Try:

```
display: none;
```

Instead of:

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Also, there's some helpful articles on the interweb on the difference between `visibility` and `display`. [For example, this article states the following](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/visibility-vs-display/):

> On the surface display: none might seem to be the same is visibility:
>   hidden, but it isn’t. The big difference is in that point I called out
>   above.
>
> `visibility: hidden` – the element stays in the normal document flow
>
> `display: none` – the element is removed from normal document flow so
>   surrounding html elements collapse to close the space

Comment: Since i haven't tried a lot of stuff, i have nothing to post. The only thing i posted is right there in my question, and it doesn't seem to work. I have the animation working, no help needed there.  I just dont want to be able to scroll to the right. I can't see the DIV cause its hidden, but there is a big white spot that i can scroll to. How can i fix that?

Comment: I've confirmed my answer above, using `display:none;`, removes the blank white space. http://jsfiddle.net/Ktt4Z/3/

Comment: This is great, but it has one problem - this eliminates my fly-in animation - the object just appears. Is there any way i can add a delay so the div will first be shown and then fly in?